# Call a js function into a for block

Tags: javascript, python, radio-button, tornado

I have this problem. I take a vector of data from Tornado. This vector is 'users'. 
I have this block

```
{% if users %}
{% for user in users %}
            <form name="form_user_{{ user.id }}" method="post" action="/networks/{{ net.id }}/rights">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div>
                    {{ escape(user.name) }}
                    <input type='hidden' name="id" value='{{ user.id }}'>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>

                  <label class="radio inline" onclick="document.forms['form_user_{{ user.id }}'].submit();">
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="0">
                    None
                  </label>
                  <label class="radio inline" onclick="document.forms['form_user_{{ user.id }}'].submit();">
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="1">
                    Read
                  </label>
                  <label class="radio inline" onclick="document.forms['form_user_{{ user.id }}'].submit();">
                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="4">
                    Read + Commands
                  </label>



                  {{ xsrf_form_html() }}
                </td>

              </tr>
            </form>
            {% end %}
          {% end %}
```

Now I have a js function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //function check(){

    {% if users %}
      {% if user.perm == 1 %}

      $('input:radio[name=optionsRadios]:nth(1)').attr('checked',true);
      //$('input:radio[name=sex]')[1].checked = true;

      {% elif user.perm == 4 %}  

      $('input:radio[name=optionsRadios]:nth(2)').attr('checked',true);
      //$('input:radio[name=sex]')[2].checked = true;

      {% else %}

      $('input:radio[name=optionsRadios]:nth(0)').attr('checked',true);
      //$('input:radio[name=sex]')[0].checked = true;

      {% end %}
    {% end %}

  });
```

But Tornado tells me that the variable user is not inizialized when the list of users is empty. So I would call the function into the for block, naming the function for example function check(){} I don't know...
How I can do to call the function only if the program enter in the for block?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you can't just put this `{{user.perm}}` into hidden input and then take it from js code?

If you want to do it this way, then just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //function check(){

    {% for user in users %}
      {% if user.perm == 1 %}

      $('input:radio[name=optionsRadios]:nth(1)').attr('checked',true);
      //$('input:radio[name=sex]')[1].checked = true;

      {% elif user.perm == 4 %}  

      $('input:radio[name=optionsRadios]:nth(2)').attr('checked',true);
      //$('input:radio[name=sex]')[2].checked = true;

      {% else %}

      $('input:radio[name=optionsRadios]:nth(0)').attr('checked',true);
      //$('input:radio[name=sex]')[0].checked = true;

      {% end %}
    {% end %}

  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have just put this
`code`<input type='hidden' name="perm" value='{{ user.perm }}'> `code` 
and I have modified in your way the js function end now works!!! Thank you very much!!!